# Custom Loop and Infinite Scroll

Tags: loop, plugin-jetpack, infinite-scroll

I am using customized version of _s theme where I have Product CPT.

In the following files, I need to use Infinite scroll (provided by Jetpack) -

> archive-products.php
>   taxonomy-[tax-name].php
>   home.php
>   archive.php

Now, the problem is most of these templates use custom loop (using WP_Query which ends with pagination after while()).

I have used following code in functions.php after activating jetpack and Photon module -

```
function vg_infinite_scroll_init() {
    add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
        'container' => 'page-content',
        'footer' => 'page',
        'type'   => 'click',
        'render'  => false,
    ) );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'vg_infinite_scroll_init' );
```

Also, I wrapped all posts under `#page-content` on `archive-products.php`. But the infinite scroll is not working either in scroll or in click type. Any ideas?

It is also pointed out to me that I should use the `render` arg of the infinite loop to describe my custom loop but am not sure how to do that as it would vary in every template.

**For Ex:** Following is the whole code am using in `archive-products.php` -

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    $prod_arch_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'products',
                    'posts_per_page' => '12',
                    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
                    );
    $prod_arch_query = new WP_Query( $prod_arch_args );

    if( $prod_arch_query->have_posts() ) {
        while( $prod_arch_query->have_posts() ) {
            $prod_arch_query->the_post();
            $prod_images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cmb2_prod_images', true );
            $prod_price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cmb2_prod_price', true );
    ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 product-main wow fadeInUp">
                <figure itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" class="product-item relative">
                    <div class="product-display">
                        <div class="list-pic">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php
                                foreach ($prod_images as $key => $value) {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $key, 'prod-list', 'itemprop = image' ); ?>
                                    <?php
                                    continue;
                                }
                                ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="view-detail"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View Detail</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <figcaption class="relative">
                        <div class="pro-list-title" >
                            <h3 itemprop="name">
                            <a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="pro-list-rates">
                            <div class="pro-list-rates-new">
                                <span  itemprop="priceCurrency">
                                    <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>
                                </span> 
                                <span itemprop="price"><?php echo $prod_price; ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="add-container">
                            <!-- <a class="btn btn-1 btn-1a">
                                <i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i> Add to container</a> -->
                            <?php vg_after_entry(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>

            <?php
        }
        the_posts_navigation();
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used 'init' in the add_action in my own implementation of infinite scroll, try that.

```
add_action( 'init', 'vg_infinite_scroll_init' );
```

As to your question about rendering a custom query you would do the following.

-Set the render to your function name

```
'render' => 'your_render_function,
```

-Add your function to call a specified loop template

```
function your_render_function(){
  get_template_part( 'custom-loop-content' )
}
```

create a file called custom-loop-content.php and add your custom query in there. Be aware that your query will be reset each time. I couldn't think of a way around that.